# Arangodb- does a data dictionary Exist

Tags: arangodb

does anyone know if arangodb has any sort of data dictionary available ? In essence we’re responsible for reporting and it would be helpful to be able to run a query that would enable us to list of collection and attributes so we can see has been been added/removed/updated ?

Basically an equivalent of all_tab_columns in oracle would be helpful .

Thanks

Comment: Remember, ArangoDB is a NoSQL database, so the way it handles schemas is different to an RDBMS.

Look at https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/functions-document.html to see how you can query ATTRIBUTES of documents (analogous to RDBMS columns)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `arangosh` command ([more](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.7/programs-arangosh.html)) and list all collections in a database using `db._collections()`. Then you can run a query that goes through every document in a collection and gets its `ATTRIBUTES` ([source](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.7/aql/functions-document.html#attributes)).

**Example bash script:**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Database: " DATABASE
read -p "Username: " USERNAME
read -s -p "Password: " PASSWORD

echo

ARANGOSH_SCRIPT=$(cat <<-END
  const getAttributes = (collection) => db._query(\`
    FOR rec IN \${collection}
      FOR attr IN ATTRIBUTES(rec)
        RETURN DISTINCT attr
  \`).toArray();
  db._collections().forEach((collection) => {
    if (collection.properties().isSystem) {
      // ignore system collections
      return;
    }
    const collectionName = collection.name();
    print(\`\${collectionName}: \${JSON.stringify(getAttributes(collectionName))}\`);
  });
END
)

arangosh --server.database "$DATABASE" \
 --server.username "$USERNAME" \
 --server.password "$PASSWORD" \
 --javascript.execute-string "$ARANGOSH_SCRIPT"
```